# Invalid object name in sql view

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-view

I cannot use synomyms in my project because of some deployment restrictions so instead, I created this view:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[User] AS SELECT * FROM [PersonalData].[dbo].[User] 
GO
```

It worked OK but now I need to modify it as follow:

```
ALTER VIEW [dbo].[User] AS 
    SELECT [Id],
    t.[Name] AS [Title],
    [FirstName],
    [LastName],
    [JobTitle],
    [Department],
    [EmailAddress],
    [PhoneNumber],
    [PhoneExtension],
    [MobilePhoneNumber],
    [CreatedDate],
    [ModifiedDate],
    [Uid],
    [Active]
    FROM [PersonalData].[dbo].[User] AS u
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [PersonalData].[dbo].[Titles] AS t ON u.TitleId = t.Id 
GO
```

Currently, it fails with:

```
Ambiguous column name 'Id'
```

in the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` line.

However, the Microsoft SQL Management Studio highlights `[PersonalData].[dbo].[Titles]` with the error:

```
Invalid object name '[PersonalData].[dbo].[Titles]
```

In fact, it doesn´t provide me IntelliSense for that table's columns.

The table `[PersonalData].[dbo].[Titles]` is there. In fact, the following query returns results with no errors:

```
select * from [PersonalData].[dbo].[Titles]
```

My knowledge about SQL is not deep enough but I don´t understand why this is, why it finds `Users` table but doesn´t find `Titles`.

A little more context:

- The view that I am creating is not in the `PersonalData` database but in other database called `Platform`.
- I checked the context and it is OK, I am creating the view in `Platform` database.

Why does it happen?

Comment: can't you use `SELECT u.[Id] AS [id]`? It appears that creating the view is finding your `Titles` table just fine

Comment: @MattBusche If you add a little elaboration, I think you should post that as an answer to this question.

Comment: @MattBusche: this is the answer (shame of me). Please answer, I will accept it. Thanks

Comment: @MattBusche - I didn't see your comment before I posted my answer. Please post as an answer so you can get credit.

Comment: @lontivero thanks, I posted the answe below

Comment: Additionally, the reason intellisense was probably showing the table as an issue is because it can get screwed up when there is an error higher up in the query. I'm guessing fixing the id issue resolved your intellisense "issue".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the table name to your `[id]` field. Because that field is in both tables that's why it's considered ambiguous (the view doesn't know which table to get it from).

```
SELECT u.[Id] AS [id]
```

Answer (score 8):

The IntelliSense issue is peripheral, and it may be because of:

1. the previous syntax error (you need to tell SQL Server *which* `Id` you mean, since it exists in both tables), or
2. that your local IntelliSense cache is stale. You can fix this by issuing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> or using `Edit > IntelliSense > Refresh Local Cache` (and, depending on the network connection to the server, waiting seconds or even minutes).

That said, I would suggest two changes, one serious and one just a best practice:

1. Don't name columns `Id`. The name is completely meaningless. Is it a `UserID`? Ok, call it `UserID` wherever it appears in the schema.
2. Properly prefix *all* of the columns in your queries, not just the ones that have a name collision. This makes your query easier to understand and prevents people having to go manually figure out which table a column comes from.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
ALTER VIEW [dbo].[User] AS 
    SELECT u.[Id],
```

It appears that both your User table and your Titles tabe have a column named "Id". It's telling you that it doesn't know which Id column you mean in your SELECT column list.